# How reliable is MongoDB's query optimizer?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

According to [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/):

> For a query, the MongoDB query optimizer chooses and caches the most
>   efficient query plan given the available indexes.

So if the query optimizer chooses one index over the other according to `indexStats`, is this a good enough evaluation to delete the unused index and keep only the preferred one?

Or are the edge cases where it makes sense to keep the index that is not preferred by the query optimizer and delete the preferred one?

Comment: If you have an index and it's never chosen and you have no plans for future queries that will use it, I would get rid of it. Each index consumes RAM and when MongoDB can no longer fit all indexes in RAM performance falls off a cliff.

Comment: @Mercer This aspect aside, I can force mongo to use the index that is not auto-chosen. My question is whether there might be a case where one should go against the query optimizer decision or if the optimizer should always have the last word.

Comment: Keep in mind that indexes work by matching the exact order of the predicate and that prefixes are allowed. That is, if you have an index `{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}`, then 1. your query must specify the keys in the order of `{a: ..., b: ..., c: ...}` in order to be indexed; 2. the queries `{a: ..., b: ...}` and `{a: ...}` will also be indexed; and 3. the queries `{a: ..., c: ...}`, `{b: ..., c: ...}`, `{b: ...}`, and `{c: ...}` will not be indexed. MongoDB can also generate compound indexes from existing indexes. Keep those points in mind when deciding whether or not the additional index is necessary.

Comment: @B.Fleming I don’t think your first statement is correct. The field order in queries does not matter, only the field sort direction.

Comment: @Manuel You're correct, my memory of the subject was a bit fuzzy. Order of keys in the query does not matter.

Comment: All useful comments but unfortunately they don’t answer my question.